# Node + TypeScript: 'this' implicitly has type 'any'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, typescript-typings

I have an issue with TypeScript which I am not able to resolve:

I am using a *mongoose schema's post function* to generate a profile(Profile model) for a user as soon as he/she signs up (via User model).

I am getting a type **error** related to **this**. Even though the code works fine. So i am using ** // @ts-ignore **

**Interfaces:**

```js
interface UserAttrs {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
// adding custom build function
interface UserModel extends mongoose.Model<UserDoc> {
    build(attrs: UserAttrs): UserDoc;
}
```

**Further code:**

```js
// schema 
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
}, { // schema options 
    toJSON: {
        transform(doc, ret) {
            ret.id = ret._id;
            delete ret._id;
            delete ret.password;
            delete ret.__v;
        }
    }
});

// generate profile for user  
userSchema.post('save', async function () {
    // @ts-ignore                              <---- TS ERROR
    let firstName = this.get('firstName');
    // @ts-ignore                              <---- TS ERROR
    let lastName = this.get('lastName');
    // @ts-ignore                              <---- TS ERROR
    let user = this.get('id');
    // @ts-ignore
    const profile = new Profile({
        firstName, lastName, user
    })
    await profile.save();
})
// configuring custom build function 
userSchema.statics.build = (attrs: UserAttrs) => {
    // builds a new user for us
    return new User(attrs);
}

const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc, UserModel>('User', userSchema)
export { User }
```

I would really appreciate the help, this is making me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `this` is not specified in the typings for the `Schema`'s `post()` method callback function. It may work anyway because the value of `this` can be a complicated thing in javascript, but it's not declared to work that way.

If you want the newly created document, then [that actually gets passed in as an argument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-post) to the callback.

```
userSchema.post('save', async (newUser) => {
    let firstName = newUser.get('firstName');
    let lastName = newUser.get('lastName');
    let user = newUser.get('id');
    //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.5.1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApnAZlCEOAckVXW2ICgqB6WuDAYwAssQBDOKp5DeAK7YoAZVbsuAXjhIsAdwTI0mLADoxbTgAoA3lTgG8wKPwByHEFgBccHXBgBPMNbgiYUYKgA0cKFgCOAsZYACY27gI4AL5e+oYANhxmFi52js42bh7evgFBfmH2UJFwMXEGEsDxNmlOLlmeKD5+gcGFEdGxhnBgSRhy0IW1Ga7ujc15beHF0VQxtnD0jOKccBBgMMB83N0wEABSIgDypjXl3UUcSBi40CBaIRBMEzAAlLbnF4Z+MKrAIXBpD9VAB9f4Abk+XzgISw8SwMBwwLBIUh0IusPhiNyv16GH6gzR6MMmIRSIRoJBADciV8oud6VFXpC6AwUFhZFAONiwARcFUcLcoHAhFhhdxRaIVhxVJB+FpiBgOFSsMQfEkHEgmHAtLI5ABVYTvSQAPg+3SxRhMMHMlkBMnkhrFqnZMAV-OtttVzPOlsSyTt0j1TqgLoRCv9NpSxB9FoRIuE9uDwjDbuI-xjLO6vGu8F5EH58KT8jgAAU+QLdFCDB6A1gutDI16G19JTZk2KGa9zhw5BxgHmK-DVEqVVofUygA)

Comment: Thanks alot really. Worked and understood.